# Why can't save the web page into my /var/www directory?

Tags: php, linux, file, file-get-contents, document-root

The document root is /var/www, I want to download the web page into /var/www/php.html

```
<?php
$url = "http://php.net";
$html_content = file_get_contents($url);
$fp = fopen("php.html","a");
fwrite($fp,$html_content);
fclose($fp);
echo $html_content;
?>
```

I can get the web page in firefox, but where is my php.html file ?

Comment: you got some advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is located in the same folder of your PHP script. If you want access to the page you should something like use http://path_to_your_script/pythons.html

To save in your /var/www you should use this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://localhost/postgres";
$html_content = file_get_contents($url);
$fp = fopen("/var/www/php.html","a"); // ADD /var/www to the path
fwrite($fp,$html_content);
fclose($fp);
echo $html_content;
?>
```

Now you can access with http://localhost/php.html

If you can't save in /var/www/ is because you don't have permission, if you have root permission you can execute this in the console: `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/`

Comment: if you can't save is because you don't have permission, if you have root permission you can execute this in the console:  sudo chmod 777 /var/www/